# Symfony buffer content to twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, buffer

I have a controller that runs a long service that outputs different messages within ob_implicit_flush and ob_end_flush...

My question is how can I flush this content to a twig template...

This is the controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Sync\Incomming\Syncronize;


/**
* @Route("/sync")
*/
class SyncController extends AbstractController
{
    private $syncronize;
    public function __construct(Syncronize $syncronize)
    {
        $this->syncronize = $syncronize;

    }
    /**
     * @Route("/",name="sync_index")
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {  


        ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
        header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
        ob_implicit_flush(true);
        $this->syncronize->updateData();
        ob_end_flush(); 
        /*How can i pass this content to the twig template ?*/
        return $this->render( 'sync/output.html.twig', ['message' => "" ]); 

    }

}
```

And here is the Tool to send the messages:

```
namespace App\Tools;

class Message
{
    static function write( string $msg, $level = 1 )
    {
        $levels=[
            '-',
            '  |_',
            '    |_',
            '      |_',
            '        |_',
        ];
        ob_implicit_flush(true);
        echo $levels[$level] . $msg . PHP_EOL;
        return ob_flush();
    }

}
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks...

Comment: From what i'm guessing you would need to run `updateData` inside your template. That's because the render function wont be called as long at that task is not finished

Answer (score 0):

In your index action instead of calling `ob_end_flush()` you could call `$messages =`[`ob_get_flush()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php).

This will also stop output buffering, but it will return the contents of the buffer as a string, which you then can use in your twig template.

Comment: The problem is that i don't want to stop the buffering... I saw on the documentation on tiwg the block {% flush %} but i can't find the way to buffer